# Log contains these entries 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed

Tags: centos, logs

I have a lot of these entries which repeats over and over again. Seem to change in duration when errors gets. Sometimes I see repeat entries after 1-3 minutes, and other times it is 20 minutes to 30 minutes.

Server is CentOS 7.7.1908 (Core) and kernel is 3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64.

```
Aug 15 11:13:33 cms03 journal: clutter_actor_set_size: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
Aug 15 11:13:33 cms03 journal: clutter_actor_show: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
Aug 15 11:13:33 cms03 journal: clutter_actor_set_size: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
Aug 15 11:13:33 cms03 journal: clutter_actor_show: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
```

Comment: this is a really old version of CentOS... anyway Clutter is a graphical library. Are you (perhaps inadvertently) using any graphical applications?

Comment: System has a desktop GUI and runs VNC server. Not sure whether the Java web application uses this library.